# How to use function pointer in multiprocessing argument

Tags: python, function, process, point

I have several functions that use the same arguments, as shown below

```
def cat(time , dist)
    return random.randint(1, 400) * time + random.randint(1, 5) * dist

def dog(time , dist)
    return random.randint(1, 300) * time + random.randint(1, 7) * dist

def rabbit(time , dist)
    return random.randint(1, 200) * time + random.randint(1, 3) * dist

def turtle(time , dist)
    return random.randint(1, 100) * time + random.randint(1, 1) * dist


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FunArray = {
        1:cat
        2:dog
        3:rabbit
        4:turtle
    }
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    q=10
    for i in xrange(1,4):
        workers = pool.apply_async(FunArray[i], args=(i, q))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I just want to run two processes simultaneously, and I would like to use a function pointer to pass the function name for the process. However, the program is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there are some syntax errors:

- No `:` end of functiton definition header.

  ```
  def cat(time , dist):
                      ^
  ```
- No `,` after each items of dictionary literal:

  ```
  1:cat,
       ^
  ```
- `if __name__ == "__main__"` block should be indented.

There's no import statements that import `random`, `multiprocessing`

`FuncArray` is actually a dictionary.

`xrange(1, 4)` yields 1, 2, 3. (4 is excluded). If you want yield 1, 2, 3, 4, you should use `xrange(1, 5)`. But, I would rather iterate the list directly with `enumerate`.

You need to save workers reference to get result back later.

---

```
import random
import multiprocessing

def cat(time , dist):
    return random.randint(1, 400) * time + random.randint(1, 5) * dist

def dog(time , dist):
    return random.randint(1, 300) * time + random.randint(1, 7) * dist

def rabbit(time , dist):
    return random.randint(1, 200) * time + random.randint(1, 3) * dist

def turtle(time , dist):
    return random.randint(1, 100) * time + random.randint(1, 1) * dist


if __name__ == '__main__':
    funcs = [cat, dog, rabbit, turtle]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    q=10
    workers = []
    for i, func in enumerate(funcs):
        worker = pool.apply_async(func, args=(i, q))
        workers.append(worker)
    for worker in workers:
        print worker.get()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```